# Possible to use both reloadItemsAtIndexPaths and reloadData if dataSource count may change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am investigating a crashing bug with a [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) via Crashlytics that generally takes this form:

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException Invalid update:
>   invalid number of items in section 0. The number of items contained in
>   an existing section after the update (25) must be equal to the number
>   of items contained in that section before the update (27), plus or
>   minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (1
>   inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into
>   or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

I believe this is caused because I have a collectionView that periodically refreshes itself with data from a server, and that data from the server may have more or fewer items than are contained in the client [`UICollectionViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/).

When I get new data from the server, I call `reloadData` on my collection view.

However, it is possible that, due to user interaction with my collection view before the network download had completed, I had called [`reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:) just before. `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` does not appear to finish for at least a few hundred ms and many processor cycles. Hence, this crash, when the dataSource is updated in the middle of a `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`.

Is there an 'immediate' form of `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`? Or must I always be calling [`reloadData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadData) given my use case, which does appear to update everything immediately and leave the `UICollectionView` in a good state at the end.

---

**Edit**

Here is what I have done, per advice from TwoStraws:

```
    // Prevent data source from batch updating while we work
    self.dataSource.locked = YES;

    [self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.dataSource.locked = NO;
    }];
```

Then in my data source class, upon receipt of results from the server, I always call `assignResults`:

```
- (void)assignResults:(NSMutableArray *)newResults {
    if (!self.locked) {
        self.results = newResults;
        [self.delegate handleDataSourceUpdated:self];
    } else {
        self.pendingResults = newResults;
    }
}

- (void)setLocked:(BOOL)locked {
    _locked = locked;

    if (!locked && self.pendingResults) {
        [self assignResults:self.pendingResults];
        self.pendingResults = nil;
    }
}
```

As you can see, results only get assigned if the data source is not locked; otherwise they are assigned when the data source is unlocked by the `UICollectionViewController`. Note that all of these methods are happening on the main thread so I do not need to worry about synchronization of my boolean property, `locked`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Race conditions are always complicated issues, as I'm sure you know. If I understand you correctly, you're modifying the data source of the collection view while it's still trying to reload itself, which would mean the solution is to keep a separate data store that gets copied across to the collection view's data source atomically.

So:

- Collection view reads from data source A.
- Network writes to data source B.
- At a point you specify, copy B into A in one fell swoop.
- Tell the collection view to reload.

That way the collection view should never have to worry about race conditions – it always reads from a fixed set of data as far as it's concerned.

Comment: It's not clear to me that a UICollectionView will continue to "point" to data source A during the entire duration of a reloadItemsAtIndexPaths in this approach. Do we know if that how UICollectionView does/is supposed to work?

Comment: You can detect when a collection view starts and finishes its updates by using the completion block on its `performBatchUpdates()` method – AFAIK that ought to only be triggered when the loading has definitely finished. If you have a very complicated situation you may need to use a boolean property to mark "I'm about to start updates" and "I've definitely finished, it's safe to copy."

Comment: Thank you @twostraws -- that is what I have done as you can see in my edits above.